# How do I deliver a baby?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm playing Fallout Shelter, and my newest bonus objective is to "**Deliver 1 Baby Dweller.**"

I've already figured out that I can put a male vault dweller and a female vault dweller together in some residential quarters, and and eventually, if they hit it off, the lady will replace her vault suit with a yellow sweater and a decidedly pregnant figure.

Good enough.

But how long does it take her to deliver the child? Do I have to induce it through some sort of tapping ritual or placing her in the correct room? Does the pregnant dweller need to stay in the living quarters, or can I put her to work in my Diner or Water Treatment Facility? Do the SPECIAL stars of the parents matter?

Tell me everything about [how to make babies](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll-lia-FEIY) and what I can do to control the process.

Comment: Additional data: apparently the game blocks you from arming a pregnant woman and sending her out to explore the Wasteland. If you assign her to work in a room and an industrial accident or radroach infestation occurs, she will flee, screaming, while other vault dwellers clean up the mess and put out the fires.

Comment: Arqade never stops to amuse me with question titles.

Answer (score 116):

**Mating**: Bring a male and a female Dweller together into the living quarters. In larger living quarters you can bring in more Dwellers and let them work it out. The higher the Charisma the faster they will mate.

Direct offsprings will not mate, the game prevents incestuous behavior. If you do not keep log of your bloodlines (which you most probably don't) there are two ways to detect blood relationship:

1. By default new borns will get the last name of the father. So if two dwellers have the same last name, they might be related.
2. In case related dwellers are in the living quarters, they will bring up the topic that it is nice to meet with the family.

**Pregnancy**: While women are pregnant they can work. But they will not take care of any incidents but run into the living quarters instead. Make sure to assign at least one male/non-pregnant Dweller to all stations and don't equip pregnant women with weapons since they don't use them.

**Deliver Baby**: After mating it takes 3 hours for a baby to be born. You do not have to be in the game for this whole time. Just come back after 3 hours and you'll have a baby.

[image: A new baby is born]

Make sure to have enough room in your living quarters. If your vault is full, women will simply stay pregnant until there is free room. There won't be an indicator and neither the pregnant dwellers will complain in any way. (Also see maximum population below)

**Growing up**: It takes another 3 hours until children are fully grown up. In their stats they have a grow-up-bar. During this time they can not be assigned to jobs. Again you do not have to be in the game during this time.

**Overpopulation**: Take care to not grow too fast. Once a baby is born you will need to feed it. Since children won't work you quickly run out of resources and have to juggle your workforce between your water treatment plants and diners if you get too many babies at once.

**Maximum Population**: The maximum number of dwellers in the vault is 200 - if you reach 200 dwellers, you have to be very careful placing men and women together in living quarters, or you'll have a whole lot of perpetually-pregnant females.

Comment: Very nice answer, one more thing you should mention is that parents can't mate with their child. I once put mother and son in the living quarters (I didn't realize that they are mother and son) and they just sat there saying it's nice for a family to be together.

I didn't experiment with cousins though :)

Comment: Good point. I added that. I can't tell about cousins or other constellations. I actually quit the game a day after I wrote above answer. :-)

Comment: While the preggos can work, they won't have the baby until you station them in a residence room.  I've had some on the job for way more than 3 hours and none of them have delivered... moved them all into apartments and they started popping them out.  :)  Also, you need to be on top of high charisma guys.  I left a couple together for too long, they had a baby, then he got her preggo again immediately!! ack!  How am I supposed to feed all these kids!!  lol

Comment: @EJA - That's probably more to do with maximum population.  Pregnant women stay pregnant until there's room for their kids.  You probably built a new residence and moved them in... thereby creating more room.

Comment: @Bobson - Good point.  I've now witnessed babies popping out while mom worked, so you must be correct on why I didn't see that happen before.  Up to 42 people now, the resource drain is real!  :)

Answer (score 17):

You need to wait three hours of game time, so quite a while. Then it will stay as a child for another three hours before being useable.

Comment: Kids grow up so fast these days...

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, it's about 3 hours of game-time. And they can totally work and all that, just know that they run away if there's a fire or infestation so it's good to pair them with non-pregnant dwellers so someone can deal with the incidents.

No need to tap or do anything special. You'll just get a pop up that says a baby was delivered and then you can name it! (You can also rename any of your dwellers by tapping on their name in their little stats windows.

My shelter definitely houses the cast of The Office ;)