# Radio Station: One or many?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Having read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223879/increase-population-with-radio-station-advantage-over-pregnancy) for a general idea of how Radio Stations work, and having experimented a bit, I'm wondering whether having **separate** multiple radio stations mean that multiple signals will go out at regular intervals?

I know that having multiple stations **together** as one unit would just mean that one signal would be sent faster, even more so by adding more charismatic people and so on.

So for example, if we have two separate radio rooms, do two signals go out every signal period?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have multiple radio stations, and they update at different intervals. I can confirm that having multiple radio stations will give you more opportunities to pull in followers, as each independently check for new followers when their respective countdown's trigger.

Comment: They also both help with happiness, I got 3 stations and it boost happiness a lot more than a sole one.

Answer (score 1):

I use multiple stations, as they can be placed around the map. Just one is a little bit too low. Maybe you lost too many dwellers to raiders. You need a fast way to get new people. The birthrate is good too, but those pregnant women won't fight in the case of a raid. I've placed currently 2 around on the map and if I build a new barracks I can get 2 new citizens right away. :-)