# How to get more dwellers fast

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've got 16 dwellers as of now, sadly 4 died in a tragic accident.....
I really need to get more dwellers because all my water workers died.

I have tried to make babies but most of my dwellers have very bad charisma. To add to that I am short on workers as I did have a bigger population but it dropped very quickly, so I am losing happiness.

Comment: Related: [Increase population with Radio Station / Advantage over pregnancy?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/223879/108003)

Comment: Low charisma isn't really an issue. That just makes it take a little longer to get pregnant initially. Even with 1 charisma, you should be able to put a couple dwellers in the living quarters, and have a pregnant dweller a little later that day.

Comment: Also, dress for the occasion. I have two pieces of Nightwear (+3 charisma) reserved for my 'breeding program'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it's a struggle to catch back up, but the only thing you can do to directly get dwellers more quickly is get your dwellers to make babies. Other than that, just try to get your shelter back to operating as well as possible, as well as having room for more dwellers to come by.

You can also have a certain room that you can assign a dweller to that will let a dweller use a radio to call out for more dwellers. You have to have 20 dwellers before you can get the room.

Comment: The [Radio Studio](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Radio_studio) requires 20 dwellers.

Comment: The Radio Room is also really bad for getting new dwellers.  With 2 10 CHA Dweller using +5 clothes, it's about 8 hours per chance of getting a dweller.  At starter level CHA, you're talking about 50+ hours per chance.  You can give birth 15+ times in that period.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to gain more Dwellers

- The [Radio Studio](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Radio_studio) is an option, but you need 20 Dwellers to unlock it; and when manned by low-charisma dwellers, attracting new Dwellers might take some time. Note that Charisma can be boosted with certain Outfits.
- You can put two Dwellers together in your Living Quarters. Conceiving might take some time (note: the right Outfits also help here), as well as carrying the child and having it grow out to be an adult. There are however no pre-conditions for this approach, the outcome is pretty much guaranteed.
- And lastly, you can send Dwellers into the Wasteland. Occasionally, your Dwellers will stumble upon a Red Rocket Truckstop, a Super Duper Market etc. Once in a while, there's refugees in there that want to join your Vault. Also, these explorers might find Outfits that boost Charisma, to help with the two points above.

Answer (score -2):

Keep on breeding them and here's a good way to get more supplies to upgrade living quarters and to get suits.

1. wait until LATE LATE night.
2. Sent a dweller with armor and lots of radaway and stimpacks
3. Wait for 6:30 pm the next day.

Large chance for dwellers and rare stuff. I got 1000000000 Caps

Comment: This assumes OP is pretty far in the game, I think, but in the question, they said they only have 16 dwellers, which seems like they are pretty early on. The issue seems to be maintaining happiness and resources while trying to increase population, but this solution doesn't really account for that and could potentially make the situation worse...

Comment: The Caps cap is 999999 (without lunchboxes). There's no chance of dwellers from plain wasteland exploration. The time of day has no effect.

Answer (score -3):

It might seem like it takes forever to get dwellers but some things you can do to get dwellers are to make babies, open up lunch boxes sometimes they will give you a special dweller in there, also you can build a radio place.

Comment: This does not add anything new to the answers already here, though.