# What happens when you deliver a baby offline?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Do I need to be online for it to deliver? If not, does it name itself automatically?

Does anything else happen such as growing up if I am not online?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deliver a baby?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223800/how-do-i-deliver-a-baby)

Comment: The top answer in this question does answer "What happens when you deliver a baby offline?" too, but that's coincidental. The original question is not the same as this one. We shouldn't close questions just because they already have a deeply buried answer on this SE...

Comment: You didn't read that question's top answer, did you? He explains everything thoroughly. "You do not have to be in the game for this whole time. Just come back after 3 hours and you'll have a baby."

Comment: I **know** the top answer also answers this question. But the _questions_ are not duplicates. I think [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate) on meta sums it up pretty well. Moreover, in this case, the answers are not exactly the same, it's just that this question's answer is **included** in another, **unrelated** question. If you want to discuss this further, please ask a question on meta.

Answer (score 4):

You do have to be online to deliver a baby.

If a baby is about to be born when you're offline, i.e. three hours have passed, it will wait until you open the game again to come out :) You will be able to name him/her at this moment. A baby will never name him/herself automatically.

Considering that growing up essentially just adds the possibility to make a dweller work, what difference does it make if it happens offline?

To explain a bit more, nothing really happens "offline". The game does not continue to run when you do not play (even if push notifications on mobile can make you think so). This is what the game does:

- When you close the game, save the state of your dwellers and the current date
- When you're offline, nothing
- When you open the game, compare the current date with the saved date and update the state of your dwellers accordingly

Comment: You have to tap the baby icon above the mothers head for the baby to be born, so this can't happen offline.

Comment: That's what I say in my answer, but maybe I wasn't clear enough. I edited it slightly for clarity.

Comment: Ok, then I just misunderstood you. I edited it further for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be online to deliver the baby.

It takes three hours for a pregnant woman to be ready to give birth. It doesn't matter if you're online or not, that's the minimum time it takes. Once the three hours have taken place, and you've logged back in if you've been away, you get an animation and a baby icon appears above the woman to show she's ready to give birth.

That's how she stays until you click the icon. She could remain pregnant forever if you don't deliver the baby. Once you do that, the child appears and you give it a name.

The child now needs another three hours to grow up. Again, you can be online or offline, it doesn't matter. But there's no icon clicking to do when going from child to adult - so if you deliver a child, then log out for more than three hours, then log back in again, you'll find the child has grown into an unassigned adult dweller.

So, to answer the three questions in your post in order: Yes, No and Yes.